# Hashing of strings in Java

Tags: java, hash, byte

My question is concerning the code, which is producing the hash values for strings, summing 4 bytes at a time. It's completely working, but I can't understand some of lines of this code, namely the idea which is performed in some lines. Therefore I need the help of some of yours who is rather familiar with hashing.

Well this is the full code:

```
long sfold(String s, int M) {
 int intLength = s.length() / 4;
 long sum = 0;
 for (int j = 0; j < intLength; j++) {
   char c[] = s.substring(j * 4, (j * 4) + 4).toCharArray();
   long mult = 1;
   for (int k = 0; k < c.length; k++) {
 sum += c[k] * mult;
 mult *= 256;
   }
 }

 char c[] = s.substring(intLength * 4).toCharArray();
 long mult = 1;
 for (int k = 0; k < c.length; k++) {
   sum += c[k] * mult;
   mult *= 256;
 }

 return(Math.abs(sum) % M);
```

}

Here each char value is converted to long integer type, summing the result on each iteration of the for-loop. These 2 doubtful lines of code which I mentioned above are as follows:

```
sum += c[k] * mult;
mult *= 256;
```

Well, I can understand the whole code, except these 2 lines...

1) Why we need variable 'mult'? Is it probably a usage of multiplication method for hashing?

2) Why we multiply 'mult' exactly by 256 on each iteration? What is 256 in this case?

If some of you have faced with this code or you know the idea, which is performed in these lines, please help me to understand it too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the fact that `c[k]` is char it has size of 8 bits and 8 bits is exactly 256 possible numbers. So for example we have `char[] c = new char[]{'a, 'b', 'c', 'd'}`, here `'a'` in a bit wise form would look something like `10000001` and `b` something like `10000010` and so on. Now the question is how we form `sum`, firstly we just take our `a` representation in bit wise, so `sum` become `10000001`, next we take `b` in bit wise form and multiply it to `256` which is in fact just bit wise shift on 8 bits to left, that means that `'b' * 256` is the same as `10000001 * 100000000 = 1000000100000000` (256 in bit form is 100000000) and now when we add this `'b' * 256` with previous sum, that means just substituting last 8 bits with `a` bit form. The same thing happens next.

So in the end we just receive a number which is bit wise concatenation of our previous `char`s (for example `10000001 10000010 10000011 10000100`).

I hope that would help.

Comment: Thank you so much for such an excellent explanation! I've finally got it. But I have just on additional question. If we use the unsigned int instead of char, so we need to multiply by 65536, right?

Comment: if it is in java, then you need 4294967294 (java int is 32 bits), but java don't have unsingned ints. It is always better to use `1 << 8` or `1 << k` for this king of operation (`1 << 8 = 256`);

Comment: yes, you are right, I was mistaken, wrote about 16 bits (type short for example). But the idea is correct, is it? So we multiply by 65536 and we shift to the next position.

Comment: it all depends on the size of your type (8, 16, 32 or 64 bits)

Comment: in C++ for unsigned ints - yes

Comment: Got it! that is what I wanted to hear from you, to be confident that I understood right. Thanks again and wish you nice day!

Comment: Hi! One little question about char type. You write that char has the size of 8 bits, but the code is written in Java, and Java provides char with 16 bits, as it written in Java documentation ([link]http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). So maybe you've meant char in C++, which has the size of 8 bits?

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying by `256` is actually shifting bits to the left by 8 positions (1 byte).

So, what it does is:

- it keeps the bits of the first character in lowest 8 bits (first byte),
- next character's 8 bits are in the next 8 positions (next byte), and so on, up to four.

I'll give an example for 4-bit system (we would multiply by 16 in that case):

```
c[0] = 1101
c[1] = 1001 
c[2] = 0010 
c[3] = 0110
```

it builds `long` sum whose bits look like:

```
0110 0010 1001 1101
c[3] c[2] c[1] c[0]
```

Comment: Alright! Thought that I could accept several answers, but I have to select just one. So it was the first one, which appeared here, sorry. But nevertheless thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The code basically goes one `byte` at a time.  Each byte is 8 bits, or the number 256.  In other words, multiplying by 256 is like shifting the value to the left by one byte.

Comment: You can always upvote several answers that you do find useful, and please do accept one answer.